# Cannot upload a file downloaded with curl above a certain size in selenium

Tags: python, linux, selenium, google-chrome, curl

I'm running selenium on a linux server with Xvfb and trying to upload images to instagram . I'm downloading them from the same python script selenium is running from with curl.
But I get this chrome error when the file is approximately above 5 MB:

```
RESULT_CODE_INVALID_CMDLINE_URL
```

But the script is able to upload a file above 5 MB when it is not donwloaded from the script but uploaded by hand via FTP to the server.

Here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui
import os

os.system("curl https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA00001.jpg > /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/temp/PIA00001.jpg")

mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Galaxy S5" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=540,960")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
delay = 10

# We login to instagram
try:

    connect_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/div[2]/button')))
    connect_button.click()

    login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div/label/input')
    login.send_keys('login')

    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div/label/input')
    password.send_keys('password')
    password.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER)
except:
    print('login error')

# We bypass a useless popup
try:

    cancel_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div/button')))
    cancel_button.click()
except:
    print('error bypassing first popup')

# We bypass another useles popup
try:
    cancel_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div')))
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')

    for b in buttons:
        try:
            if b.text == "Cancel":
                b.click()
                print("Cancel")
        except:
            pass
except:
    print('error bypassing second popup')

# We click on the upload button
upload_button = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]')))
upload_button.click()

# We upload the image
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l')
pyautogui.write('/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/temp/PIA00001')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Sorry if the code looks a bit messy, I have a hard time using selenium with Instagram.

I have tried many ways to download images and it happens every time.

Any help ?

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: Try using Selenium and webdriver.  Target the <input type = "FILE"> tag and use send keys to send the file's path.  (that'll set it's "value" attribute....) Click the upload button and you are done.

Comment: @pcalkins It's unfortunately not working on the website I'm wanting to upload my file to.

Comment: can you explain what that curl command is doing?

Comment: @pcalkins It's downloading an image from a website (example: https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/png/PIA00001.png) and saving it in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/temp/` as `PIA00001.jpg`

Comment: I think you need to post more code here... how do you confirm when the download is finished?  (or does curl take care of that?)  Where are the Selenium bits?

Comment: The size and error may both be red herrings.  I saw a thread that mentioned something about Chromium having way too many files open when this happened... Are you only sending one file?

Comment: @pcalkins I have added the code to the post

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in Chromium while in mobile emulation mode.  Try running in normal browser mode and see if you get the same results.

Comment: @pcalkins Unfortunately, Instagram won't let you upload if you're not on a mobile browser

Comment: Are you sure you want Ctrl-L there?  Doesn't that take you to the location bar?

Comment: @pcalkins That's the point, I open the location bar to type the path to my image and then hits enter to upload the image. I don't think there is a problem here because it seems to work with some images.

Comment: I don't understand how that could possibly work.... I guess there's some javascript that listens for changes in the location bar?  Maybe post the JS that performs the upload.  Still, when you press enter, there's going to be an issue at the browser level.  It's going to try to navigate to the file.

Comment: you may also want to consider using Selendroid/Appium and a Droid ADB/emulator for this.

Comment: @pcalkins Clicking on 'upload_button' opens linux file manager, then the Ctrl-L opens the location bar of the explorer, the path to the image is written and then we hit enter. If everything is going normal, it would close the file manager and the file would be uploaded to instagram. And sometimes the file manager is closed but I got `RESULT_CODE_INVALID_CMDLINE_URL` in chrome. Sorry if it's unclear

Comment: @pcalkins I'll look into this, thank you !

Comment: ah, gotcha... I thought it was going to the browser's location bar.  For what it's worth I've never seen "RESULT_CODE_INVALID_CMDLINE_URL" appear during a Selenium run.  Seems like something that instagram is doing or that Chrome is doing during the upload process.